# _id is removed when update mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When I update sub document using _id the _id part is then over writed, So I do not have any unique element for next time update. Can anyone please help me in this issue ? I am using Mongoose.js

This is the query

```
       return Organization.update({
            'orgId': values.orgId,
            "companyStatus._id": values.companyStatusId
        }, {
            $set: {
                "companyStatus.$": values.companyStatus
            }
        })
```

Here is the data before update

```
companyStatus: [{
            "name" : "Manger",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5788b9dec116c39753f77cfb")
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Open",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5788b9dec116c39753f77cfe")
        }]
```

and after update

```
companyStatus: [{
            "name" : "Manger"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Open",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5788b9dec116c39753f77cfe")
        }]
```

So I do not have unique id to update next time this record

Data I sent for Update

```
{
    "orgId": 1,
    "companyStatus": {
        "name": "TEST SUCCESS"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could share a the result of find().limit(2) for this collection? What you provide is a bit confusing.

First of all, you need to understand the behavior of $ operator in array updates:

[https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up.*S*](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_)

Your update command is replacing the entire document of 'companyStatus' array. Is like removing all keys and setting news one.

If you really want to update in this array, you can do something like this:

```
return Organization.update({
        'orgId': values.orgId,
        "companyStatus._id": values.companyStatusId
    }, {
        $set: {
            "companyStatus.$.name": values.companyStatus.name
        }
    })
```

Or you can iterate in companyStatus keys (if you want to update another fields) and create a "set" object.

Comment: Is this the only way? If I have 20 attributes in my model ? Do I have to write each attribute ?

Comment: "companyStatus": {
        "name": "TEST SUCCESS"
    }

Lucas this is the result of find

Comment: I don't get it.. You said "companyStatus" was an array, but then your find command return an object?

And I don't undertand.. Why you want to update objects inside an array, when you can save then as individual objects?